# rm to match multiple file extensions

Tags: linux

How to merge these two commands together

```
rm *.html
rm *.xml
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply `rm *.html *.xml`

Also see the man pages for [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) (or [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html)) or try [tldr](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr) which currently gives this output:

```
$ tldr rm

rm

Remove files or directories.

- Remove files from arbitrary locations:
    rm path/to/file path/to/another/file

- Recursively remove a directory and all its subdirectories:
    rm -r path/to/folder

- Forcibly remove a directory, without prompting for confirmation or showing error messages:
    rm -rf path/to/folder

- Interactively remove multiple files, with a prompt before every removal:
    rm -i file(s)

- Remove files in verbose mode, printing a message for each removed file:
    rm -v path/to/folder/*

$
```

Comment: If you experience an error in the above example, when there are no .html files, you could also chain the commands instead like: 
rm *.html; rm *.xml

Comment: @JohnDoe put that as your own answer, it's worth more than a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

```
rm *.html *.xml
```

It’s the shell that interprets the wildcard pattern(s) to carry out the filename expansion – not the `rm` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you experience an error with the accepted answer, when there are no .html files, you could also chain the commands instead like:
`rm *.html; rm *.xml`